# Create a contents page in word listing the tables produced?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a VBA code that basically loops through each row of an excel sheet and copies certain cells from the row and pastes it into another "Template" sheet. This template sheet is then copied into a word document. It does this for each of around 180 rows and so produces 180 templates which feed into the same word document.

I am new to VBA so please help! I have managed to add a title for the document but now I want to add a contents page after the title where each row in the contents page refers to each table in the document (i.e. 180 rows in the contents page(s) referring to the 180 tables produced. Here is my code so far:

````
Sub CreateBasicWordRepot()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application 'creates the word application variable
Dim SaveName As String
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim I As Integer
Dim intY As Integer
Dim WrdTbl As Word.Table
Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim t As Table
Dim myrange As Object



Set wdApp = New Word.Application 'starts the MS Word app (but not yet visible)

With wdApp
    .Visible = True 'Makes MS Word app visible
    .Activate 'makes MS Word the active screen
    .Documents.Add 'creates a new document
            
    With .Selection
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .BoldRun
        .Font.Size = 14
        .TypeText "<<Company Name>> IM Validation <<year>> testing template"
        .BoldRun
        .TypeParagraph
        .Font.Size = 11
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .TypeParagraph
        .InsertBreak Type:=7
        
    End With
    
    End With


        For I = 4 To 186

Worksheets("Sept 2021 tests").Select

Range("B" & I).Copy

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("B14").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sept 2021 tests").Select

Range("C" & I).Copy

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sept 2021 tests").Select

Range("D" & I).Copy

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("B5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Sept 2021 tests").Select

Range("E" & I).Copy

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("B18").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Sheets("sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B27")
tbl.Copy

With wdApp.Selection

        .PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False
       ' .Tables(I).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    End With
  
  With wdApp.Selection
    .InsertBreak Type:=7
    End With
   
 Next I
  
For Each t In wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables
    t.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
Next t
End Sub```


Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!
````

Comment: Please install the free and fantastic Ruberduck addin and use the indenter to property format your code. You should then refactor your code so that it is split into a number of functions so that it is easier to follow what you are trying to do. Adding a table of contents for tables in Word is a trivial task IF your tables have captions.  Try recording a macro that inserts a Table of Figures (to get to table of tables using the caption label drop down box).

Comment: Learn the Word object model. You would want to insert a caption for each new table. Then it is a trivial exercise to insert a Table of Tables using those captions as the source. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures BTW, "template" has a special meaning in Word jargon which does not include what you are discussing. It is a special kind of file. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm